# How can zip be used to chunk data into equal sized groups?

Tags: python

```
>>> n = 3
>>> x = range(n ** 2),
>>> xn = list(zip(*[iter(x)] * n))
```

In [PEP 618](https://peps.python.org/pep-0618/), the author gives this example of how `zip` can be used to chunk data into equal sized groups.

How does it work?

I think that it relies on an implementation detail of `zip` such that if it takes the first element of each of the elements of the list `[iter(x)] * n` that equates to the first `n` elements because of the changing state of `iter(x)` as each of the elements are taken.

This is because the following code replicates the above behavior:

```
n = 3
x = range(n ** 2)
xn = [iter(x)] * n

res = []

while True:    
        try:    
                col = []    
                for element in xn:    
                        col.append(next(element))    
                res.append(col)    
        except:    
                break
```

However, I would like to make sure that this is indeed the case and that this is a reliable behavior that can be used to chunk elements of an iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really specific to `zip`, but you basically have that right. In effect, it's zipping 3 references to the same iterator, causing it to round-robin between them. During each iteration, one more element is consumed from the iterator.

Effectively, it's the same as doing this:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> x = range(n ** 2)
>>> a = b = c = iter(x)
>>> list(zip(a, b, c))
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
```

Note that it only produces equal sized groups and may drop elements (that part is a characteristic of `zip`, because it's limited by the smallest iterable, though you could use `itertools.zip_longest` if you want):

```
>>> n = 4
>>> x = range(n ** 2)
>>> a = b = c = iter(x)
>>> list(zip(a, b, c))
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14)]
```

Comment: Definitely don't use `zip_longest` if anything could be infinite though :p

Answer (score 2):

It's not an implementation of `zip`. It's how iterables work in Python - they always "consume" and move forward.

eg:

```
whatever = iter([1, 2, 3])
next(whatever)
# 1
next(whatever)
# 2
```

What `zip` does is "advance" each object it's provided with and given the  example you've provided `[iter(x)] * n`... this becomes basically `zip(whatever, whatever, whatever)`

Since `zip` works in sequence - it takes the first `next` from `whatever` - then the `next` from `whatever` which has already moved on from the first `next`, so it's the value of `2`. Which means the next one is `3`. etc...

It's behaviour by design and the language guarantees it.